Status Code 0 in Application Gateway from some networks
Today at 12:00 I changed the DNS Entry to point to an Application Gateway instead of Azure Frontdoor. After doing that there were some failures with status code 0. The funny thing is that only POST requests were blocked. GET and Option Requests sitll worked fine. Also in the log the Application Gateway didn't seem to resolve the route to the server. The question is whether this behavior is a client side firewall issue or actually a problem with the App Gateway.
Facts:
Application Gateway WAFv2 with WAF on detection mode
Routes to App Services behind.
Post requests receive Status Code 0 with 0 bytes and no request
headers for some clients
Get and Options requests work on all clients
Occured 2-3 hours after change
Is there any logical explaination for this behavior?

A "0" could indicate that the network request is timing out. Given that you were on Front Door, I wonder if your GET requests might be resolving because they are cached (Front Door includes a CDN), and POST isn't because those aren't cached and your backend can't be reached?

Thanks for the suggestion. We changed from Frontdoor to Application Gateway, so this should not be the case. We also havn't used any cache in the past on Frontdoor. According to Microsoft this could be a too large header beeing sent. However I have no idea how only selected networks send bigger headers.

After a lot of digging we found out that we used HTTP/2 with TLSv1.3 on our Application Gateway and some firewalls which do SSL inspections, sent a HTTP/2 request with TLSv1.2 which confused the Application Gateway. The AGW dropped the entire request because of that. According to the Microsoft support it shows as a too large field in their log (refering to the header size in HTTP/2), which is technically not the root cause.
We eventually fixed it by making exclusions to the firewalls which messed up our request.
